# keyring open passwords

Tags: password, keyrings

I've acquired an old desktop. There is no sensitive data on it, nor are there passwords on there that would matter if they get stolen.

Since I use it as an alarm clock it automatically logs in. At startup another program boots which has a password stored in it that it needs. I really couldn't care less if that password gets stolen since you can only get my basic agenda with alerts (there are no specifics in my basic agenda).

The problem is that on every bootup I have to enter my password into the keyring to release this password. Is it possible to make this password accessible without the keyring?

I do want to keep the keyring because of internet passwords it automatically encrypts which actually do matter.

Comment: [This](http://davestechsupport.com/blog/2009/01/16/how-to-remove-ubuntus-password-keyring/) - and it would leave the passwords accessible.

Comment: thanks, I added an extra keyring with a simple password. Changed it's password to a black password. Deleted the old saved password that has to be left unencrypted. setted the new keyring as default. re-entered the password in the program and reset the default keyring to "default".
If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Would my answer work? I have not tested it, as I don't intend to totally unsecure my computer... :-)

Comment: it sorta worked. it gave enough info to figure it out myself. I didn't unsecure my entire computer, just that one password.

Comment: I know it would not 'totally unsecure' everything, but I use my laptop at a Sixth Form, where having your computer secure is VERY IMPORTANT...

Comment: yeah, but this desktop is behind my own firewall on my own network so I'm going to assume it's reasonably save to open it up a little bit

Comment: Mine isn't - I have to disable half the security software just to access the wifi... :-) Glad to be of help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to 'Password and Keys'

[image]

1. In the View menu, ensure By keyring is checked.
2. In the sidebar under Passwords, right-click on <kbd>Login</kbd> keyring and select <kbd>Change Password</kbd>.
   [image]
3. Enter your Old Password, and then Enter the new one as blank.

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.